# Firebase ios notification token not generated in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase-notifications

I completed all the steps followed by firebase notification document, finally when I run the app.showing the following error, how to generate device token? please refer screenshot below

**Error:**

> Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=1001 "(null)"

**I tried this code**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:156.0/255.0 green:39.0/255.0 blue:176.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];


    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max) {
        UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
        (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
        [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    } else {
        // iOS 10 or later
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
        UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions =
        UNAuthorizationOptionAlert
        | UNAuthorizationOptionSound
        | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
        [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter]
         requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions
         completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
         }
         ];

        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] setDelegate:self];
        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
        [[FIRMessaging messaging] setRemoteMessageDelegate:self];
#endif
    }
    [FIRApp configure];

    // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(tokenRefreshNotification:)
                                                 name:kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification object:nil];

   // [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications];

    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    [[FIRMessaging messaging] disconnect];
    NSLog(@"Disconnected from FCM");
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    [self connectToFcm];
}

- (void)tokenRefreshNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // Note that this callback will be fired everytime a new token is generated, including the first
    // time. So if you need to retrieve the token as soon as it is available this is where that
    // should be done.
    NSString *refreshedToken = [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token];
    NSLog(@"InstanceID token: %@", refreshedToken);

    // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
    [self connectToFcm];

    // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
}

// With "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled": NO
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] setAPNSToken:deviceToken
type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeSandbox];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification

    // Print message ID.
    NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[@"gcm.message_id"]);

    // Pring full message.
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);
}

- (void)connectToFcm {
    [[FIRMessaging messaging] connectWithCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Unable to connect to FCM. %@", error);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Connected to FCM.");
        }
    }];
}
```

console screenshot:
[image: console screenshot]

Comment: Are you testing this on a real device? Not on a simulator?